# PHP: Image optimizator

Tags: php

How would one go on about building a script that would optimize an entire folder of images (jpg's) for maximum file size reduction (at a reasonable loss of quality)?

Comment: Well, the problem is with the word "reasonable". You'd need to find some default settings manually, as it's kind of hard to create some sort of automatic image comparison, especially if it deals with aesthetics ("looks nice, still looks okay, bleh it's ugly"). Also, that will only give you a baseline - some images will look horrible on that compression setting, while others may look reasonable even with stronger compression.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a [`DirectoryIterator`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.directoryiterator.php) and a couple of GD functions:  [`imagecreatefromjpeg()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromjpeg.php)
and  [`imagejpeg()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagejpeg.php)
to do this, but you don't get much control over the output as you can only specify a percentage quality for the JPEG.

The only way to get a "reasonable loss of quality" is to review each one by hand, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

PHP includes a graphics library that can load and save images as well as manipulate them while in memory. [The docs are here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.image.php).

Functions like [`scandir()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php) will help you get a list of files in a folder, though there are lots of file functions that will help.